# Can I reset just one profile?

Tags: skylanders

Is it possible to change just one profile of the four in Skylanders? Due to the glitch after chapter 20, my grandson cannot talk to the weapon master. All three other profiles seem to work fine. I'd like to just reset the one that does not.

Comment: Then you should post your solution as an answer so that others can find it!  :-)